# How to get the most upvoted server discord.py

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So, I was making a Discord bot using discord.py and here's my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def list(ctx):
    ok = 0
    for i in db.keys():
        # lmao why is there even a while loop here @
        while ok >= 11:
            server_num = ok+1
            em = discord.Embed(title='Oldest servers in the list!',description=f'Server {server_num}')
            em.add_field(name='Name',value=db[i]['name'],inline=False)
            em.add_field(name='Description',value=db[i]['description'],inline=False)
            em.add_field(name='Tags',value=db[i]['tags'],inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=em)
            ok+=1
```

But, what I also want is that it returns the servers with most number of upvotes, we have an upvotes system and the code for it is:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1,7200)
async def upvote(ctx):
    try:
        id = str(ctx.message.guild.id)
        if id in db.keys():
            db[id]["upvote"][0] += 1
            await ctx.send(f"upvoted ")
            save()
    except commands.CommandOnCooldown:
        await ctx.send('once every 12 hours ;---------------;')
    except:
        await ctx.send('error ;-;')
```

And, every upvote is stored in a JSON file (db.json) which looks like this:

```
{
    "738049816357109831": {
        "description": "I am a good server",
        "id": "738049816357109831",
        "link": "https://discord.gg/gQ6FABc",
        "name": "Aypro's Lab",
        "review(s)": [],
        "tags": [
            "#good_boi"
        ],
        "upvote": [
            0
        ]
    }
}
```

And I am not really sure how to get the servers with most number of up votes. Thanks to who ever will answer this as it is going to really help me with my bots development.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way that I'd do it would be to incorporate a function to create a temporarily restructured dictionary that allows for you to easily get the `max` key from your json db.

```python
def get_highest_server(dictionary):
    server_votes = {}
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        server_votes[key] = dictionary[key]['upvote']
    return max(server_votes, key=server_votes.get)
```

This will iterate through your DB file and restructure it into a dictionary that has only 1 key and one value (the value being the number of upvotes).  A demonstration on using this function is as below:

```python
import json

def get_highest_server(dictionary):
    server_votes = {}
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        server_votes[key] = dictionary[key]['upvote']
    return max(server_votes, key=server_votes.get)

with open("db.json", "r") as dFile:
    databases = json.load(dFile)

highest_server = get_highest_server(databases)
```